# Luarocks: Creating a rock from package with multiple files

Tags: lua, package, luarocks

Using Luarocks, I've followed the tutorial on [Creating a rock](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Creating-a-rock). However, I'm having difficulty creating a rock of a package that contains multiple files. What do I have to do differently from the tutorial when my package is spread out across multiple files?

### Example - One File

Say I have the following file `testrock.lua`:

```
module('testrock')
function add(a, b)
    return a+b
end
```

and in `testrock-scm-1.rockspec`

```
package = "testrock"
version = "scm-1"

source = ...
description = ...
dependencies = ...

build = {
   type = "builtin",
   modules = {
       testrock = "testrock.lua"
   }
}
```

I then run `luarocks make` and it installs `testrock` just fine (I can go to another directory and run `require 'testrock'`).

### Example - Two Files

However, let's say I want to add another file `foo.lua`:

```
function testrock.sub(a, b)
    return a - b
end
```

I add the following to the end of `testrock.lua`:

```
require('foo')
```

and run `luarocks make`. `make` works, but when I then go to another directory and run `require 'testrock`` I get the following error:

`/home/<username>/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/testrock.lua:7: attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)`

and so it's complaining about the `require('foo')` statement. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `module('testrock')` hides all global variables, including the global `require` function. You can either call `require` before the call to `module`, or create a local alias (`local require = require`) before the call to `module`, or use the [`package.seeall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.seeall) option (`module('testrock', package.seeall)`).

Adding the foo module to your rockspec, so that it is installed together with your `testrock.lua` file, is straightforward:

```
-- ...
build = {
   type = "builtin",
   modules = {
       testrock = "testrock.lua",
       foo = "foo.lua"
   }
}
-- ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution came with realized that I don't need to build anything because I'm only using .lua files. Therefore, the following rockspec works:

```
package = "testrock"
version = "scm-1"

source = ...
description = ...
dependencies = ...

build = {
   type = "none",
   install = {
       lua = {
           "testrock.lua",
           "foo.lua"
       }
   }
}
```

This copies the `testrock.lua` and `foo.lua` to `/home/<username>/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/`.