# Luarock: Copying .lua files to a directory when make'ing

Tags: lua, package, luarocks

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34966948/1001930), I've just created a rockspec for a rock with just .lua files. I don't need to build anything, so I set the build option to

```
build = {
   type = "none",
   install = {
       lua = {
           "a.lua",
           "b.lua",
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

When I run `luarocks make` it works. However, I noticed that all the files are dumped into my `/home/<username>/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/` directory. I'd like for them to be in `../share/lua/5.1/<package_name>` directory. I tried doing something like

```
       lua = {
           ["<package_name>"] = "a.lua",
           ...
```

or

```
       lua = {
           ["<package_name>.<package_name>"] = "a.lua",
           ...
```

but neither method works.

Is there a way to put these files in a directory in the rockspec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy using the `builtin` build mode of rockspecs:

```
-- ...
build = {
   type = "builtin",
   modules = {
       ["mypackage.a"] = "a.lua",
       ["mypackage.b"] = "b.lua"
   }
}
```

This should install `a.lua` as `.../share/lua/5.1/mypackage/a.lua` and `b.lua` as `.../share/lua/5.1/mypackage/b.lua`, so that `require("mypackage.a")` (or `require("mypackage.b")`) just works.